# Can SANE daemon communicate with a remote network device that has a scanner attached?

Tags: wireless-networking, scanner, xsane

My understanding is that SANE is a service that sits between the user level programs and the physical scanner itself, and that SANE provides an API to the programs that it then relays to the physical machine? (not sure if Im right about that)
The typical setup seems to be where the scanner is connected directly to the computer running SANE, e.g. via USB

My scenario is, I have a Brother MFC-J6910DW multifunction connected to the network with its own physical scanner.

I'm assuming this machine does NOT run the SANE service on it (although I could be wrong)

In that case is SANE capable of "reaching out" across the network and continuing to provide its service/API or does SANE have be running on the same computer with the scanner installed?